# Merge text files by similar name

Tags: perl, merge

I am trying to combine/merge the context of thousands of text files in one folder. I am running Windows and could either use perl or shell script. The names are as following.

0001_001.txt
0001_002.txt
0001_003.txt

0002_001.txt

0003_001.txt
0003_002.txt
0003_003.txt
0003_004.txt
........

And I want them to combine as following files. For example, file name start with 0001 will merge as 0001.txt. And all new merge files will save to another folder.

0001.txt
0002.txt
0003.txt
.......

I know how to simply merge files but have no idea to group them by names. Could someone give me some ideas? 
Many Thanks

Comment: In a shell, you could simply do: `cat 0001_*.txt > 0001.txt`. And repeat for your other groups of files. But if you have a lot of groups, then yeah, it'd be best to find a programmatic solution.

Comment: Thank you very much. I try the same idea as you. I use TYPE 0001_*.txt > 0001.txt and generate the TYPE command by using EXCEL auto complete. Then past it on the text file saving to .bat file. Very intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will do the trick.

```
opendir my $dh, $source_dir or die $!
my %h;
while ( my $name = readdir($dh) ) {
   $name ~~ /^(\d+)_(\d+).txt$/ or warn "Bad file name"
   $h{$1}{$2} = 1;
}
while (my ($name, $parts) = each %h) {
    for my $part ( sort keys %$parts ) {
        concatfile( "$name\_$part.txt", "$name.txt")
    }
}
```

You need to write concat file yourself though

Comment: Thank you very much, Jose. Your code solved my problem, too.  I will use  it as a function when I have to include it in my project.